# Manipulate track length metadata in mp3 files

Tags: metadata, mp3, id3

I have to play various mp3 files on a given software without showing any information that could lead to the recognition of the played track (some kind of quiz). For that, I want to change the displayed track length to an arbitrary value. I can easily change up standard ID3 tags like "name", "artist" and so on. But changing the displayed track length seems to be more tricky, though...

Edit (after Vikram's response):

So far, I was able to manipulate the displayed track length by modifying the 'xing' header in a vbr encoded mp3 file. More precisely, I changed the bytes in the 'number of frames' section with a hex editor which lead to an mp3 that showed a modified track length according to:

```
Track length = Number of Frames * Samples Per Frame / Sampling Rate
```

with the file still being correctly played. This approach seems to work for winamp, vlc player and windows in general. Unfortunately, it does not seem to work for the proprietary software I have to use. When using that software, somehow the original track duration is still identified because a different calculation method is applied.

Any other ideas on how the track duration could be calculated resp. fooled into displaying an arbitrary value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

YES and NO.

Most of the .mp3 files have this extra info besides ID3 in XING header, which contains duration of the file.

You can modify this header to put wrong info.

Or you can simply remove this XING header!

There are two types of .mp3 files: CBR and VBR.
CBR is most common. So, using bitrate info, players still can estimate length of the audio for CBR.

For VBR this is not always correct!

So, the audio file you had was most likely an VBR encoded mp3 without XING header.

Answer (score 1):

The track length is calculated by parsing the whole MPEG audio stream, a fairly straight forward process. [XING (or similar)](https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=MP3#VBRI.2C_XING.2C_and_LAME_headers) headers (correctly: frames) exist as a help like an additional index for seeking in the file, but it is not mandatory; it also only exists because 25 years ago in most cases it would have taken too much performance to fully parse files and keeping relevant data in memory when VBR was "invented". Metadata, where you could define incorrect track lengths (like the [TLEN frame thru ID3v2](https://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames)) aren't mandatory either.

So: it's not possible. You rather found software/players that opt for performance without assuring everything they spot. Also no other file/stream format comes to my mind where a track length is mandatory and cannot be calculated by parsing the file.